# Dynamic search filter with multiple factors in web app

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, search, stored-procedures, filter

I'm building a real estate website and I'm a little bit confused on how to filter apartment search results. The user can filter his search by clicking on check boxes and a textbox that contains keywords to search for.

My problem is that I have many filtering options (by city and/or location  in city and/or apartment size and/or number of bed rooms and/or ... ). so my problem is how to write a mysql stored procedure that can be dynamic to accept different inputs and give back filtered results with pagination. for example, someone can choose number of bedrooms to be 2 or 3 in his filter and to be in a certain city and simply he might not care about the other conditions. And the user might also put a keyword along with the conditions to search for. I'm using Spring MVC and mysql but I guess the help I need is more about the concept than about what languages and relational DB I'm using.

At first, I though of passing key value pairs but this will complicate things a lot in the procedure I guess and will depend on enum tables. so, can you please suggest a proper way to implement this kind of search based on best practices and your expertise.

Many thx

Answer (score 0):

Faceted Search is really an analytic problem, meaning your need an analytic schema to do it properly.

This means a dimensional design. It also means OLAP-*style* querying.

So, you should [read up](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45655/what-are-measures-and-dimensions-in-cubes/45669#45669) on those first.

Basically, you want one big table (where each row is a house for sale), with all applicable columns. This doesn't have to be a real table, it could be a view or materialized view.

I'd pass on using sprocs for this. I don't see how it would help.

Comment: Thx for your answer .. but while I was searching about similar filtering and searching (like ecoomerce sites) a lot of SO related questions used either normal queries (some of them built the queries in javascript)  or sprocs to get the data .. they make ajax call with their catgories or filters and build the query on the backend, or send the built query from JS .. is that wrong?

Comment: You can do it anyway you want. My answer tells you the best way